# Solr filter query not working on field

Tags: solr

I have a Solr setup with some fields (see below) and also a language field. I want to return only the results with language `nl_NL`.

However if I do a filter query on `/solr/client/query?q=test&fq=language:nl_NL` I get no results back.

It seems that the `fq` is not working on this specific field. However, a query on `/solr/client/query?q=test&fq=id:1` works fine.

Are there any special requirements for a filter query to work on a field? Here is an overview of my `schema.xml`.

```xml
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="title" type="text_nl" indexed="false" stored="true" />
<field name="content" type="text_nl" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
<field name="permalink" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
<field name="image" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
<field name="date" type="tdate" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="category" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
<field name="language" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" />
```

The result when using the query with a fq on id is:

```
    {
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":4,
    "params":{
      "q":"test",
      "fq":"id:3968"}},
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"3968",
        "title":"Scotch en Soda",
        "permalink":"http://www.example.com/merken/scotch-soda/",
        "image":"http://www.example.com/SS15-SCOTCH-SODA-BRAND-PAGE-150x150.jpg",
        "date":"2015-06-22T16:02:47Z",
        "category":"brands",
        "language":"nl_NL"}]
  }}
```

Comment: can you paste the result of second query i.e "/solr/client/query?q=test&fq=id:1"

Comment: Can you confirm that `nl_NL` is the exact(case sensitive) text that you want to search ?

Comment: I have added the result for a filter query on id. I can also confirm that `nl_NL` is the exact case sensitive text that I want to search.

Comment: You schema says 'language` is not multivalued field. but `"language":["nl_NL"]` contains the square brackets. Can you say why?

Comment: I'm not sure why they are shown as multi-valued. I have changed my schema.xml and test result.

Comment: Language field - index:false???? It should be true if u want to use this field for searching..

Comment: Thanks, that did the tric. Such a simple and elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Initially I though its the issue of fieldType for the language field, but thats not the case. As the field type is string, make sure you are not mentioning the part of the string for the language in the filter.

Whatever the values has been added while indexing it has to be exactly the same for the filter. then it will work for you.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "not mentioning the part of the string for the language in the filter". Do you mean not including 'language' in the fq?

Comment: I tested the same at my end ...its just works fine only difference is I have the different fieldType

Comment: Which fieldType do you use?

Comment: here is the fieldtype used by me<fieldType name="text_ws" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
<analyzer type="index">
<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" preserveOriginal="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>

Comment: <analyzer type="query">
<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>

Comment: but I dont think the issues is with fieldType ...still we can give a try...:)

Comment: I guess you are right. Changing the fieldType did not lead to the desired result. Very strange issue this.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an index=true field on the language field did the trick. Thanks Suhel Meman!